# State of the World HazelCast Map with Listener

Tags: dictionary, hazelcast, distributed-cache

With Hazelcast, I imagine a common scenario is that consumers want to know about the current State of the world (what ever is currently in the Map) and then updates with nothing lost in between.

Imagine a scenario where a Hazelcast map is holding some variety of data that a consumer wants to be streamed (maybe via Rx) the current state and then any updates from the listener.

The API suggests that we add a Listener for updates and treat the Map as a normal ConcurrentMap.  However, while I'm enumerating the Map, updates may come in via the listener, so ensuring the correct order of items is hard.

We could share a lock between the map enumerator and the listener, but that seems a bit of a code smell.

So my question in general is, if we want to stream the SoTW and then updates, how can we do this?  Is there anything built into Hazelcast that can help us?

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304623/hazelcast-map-listener-with-replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, and I guess it is just unluckily explained, a map has no order!

The second thing, a Hazelcast map is a non snapshotting, non-persistent data-structure. Just like a ConcurrentHashMap, changes to the data-structure are reflected to the iterator and vice-versa.

Events, on the other side, are a completely independent system, especially since events are delivered asynchronously. So it might happen, that the events actually arrives before you advanced the iterator up to the same element or the other round.

If you need a better guarantee, iterate first, add the listener, apply changes (you need to do a delta in a second iteration) between start of the first run and events that you might have missed. Not an actually nice way to handle it but I don't think there's another way.

Comment: Thanks @noctarius.  In terms of the order of the Map, I don't really care, but it's the ordering of the enumeration and then updates.

I'm wondering if a good guarantee would be having a lock around the initial enumeration and have that also lock on the events.  At least they're blocked behind

Comment: That would mean you block the event threads which might cause loosing events. The best way might be to collect all events that come in during the initial read of the map and replay all events after the initial read is done. That means that some updates might be "duplicates" but the final state is the same.

Comment: If we block, the events "should" be queued up behind.  Your second suggestion is pretty much what we've done. :)